# Dynamically hiding menu items

Tags: wpf, xaml, menu

I have a menu built with xaml, and the MenuItem has the property ItemTemplate set to the following template:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="MenuItemTemplate" DataType="{x:Type mainMenu:MenuItem}" ItemsSource="{Binding ChildMenuItems}">
     <MenuItem Command="{Binding Command}" CommandParameter="{Binding CommandParameter}" Header="{Binding Path=Header}" Visibility="{Binding Visible, Converter={converter:BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

When I change the value of the property Visible to false with the intention of hiding the sub-menu what I have as a result is this:

[image]

The sub-menus are hidden but they still take some space. How can I change that to adapt to the number of items left in the menu?

**Edit:**

Here's the code from the converter:

```
public class BooleanToVisibilityConverter : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (bool) value ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would try also turning off IsEnabled, IsHitTestVisible ...   Not sure why it does not collapse

Comment: Tried that as well, didn't work

Comment: Next I would try style on the Menu with a target type of MenuItem.   But that will probably not work any better than last comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be using a `HierarchicalDataTemplate` to define your child `MenuItem`s. Instead, try using the `MenuItem.ItemsSource` property:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MenuItemTemplate" DataType="{x:Type mainMenu:MenuItem}">
    <MenuItem Command="{Binding Command}" CommandParameter="{Binding CommandParameter}"
        Header="{Binding Path=Header}" Visibility="{Binding Visible, Converter={
        converter:BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding ChildMenuItems}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

---

UPDATE >>>

Yeah sorry, you need to set the child `MenuItem` properties in a `Style` set as the `MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle`. Rather than explain it all here, I prefer to direct you to the [Binding menus using HeirarchicalDataTemplates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/llobo/binding-menus-using-heirarchicaldatatemplates) page from Lester's WPF\SL Blog on MSDN, which explains how to do it well.

Also, if you're going to data bind the `MenuItem`s, then you might as well remove the relevant items from the data bound collection instead of trying to set the `Visibility`. The UI will look the same, but it will be much simpler. It's always best to manipulate the data elements in WPF when you can, rather than the UI elements.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you are returning `Visibility.Hidden` from your converter. Instead return `Visibility.Collapsed`.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.visibility.aspx):

[image]

---

Moreover WPF provides `BooleanToVisibilityConverter`, you don't need to re-define it unless doing something extra. You can add resource under App resource section like this and use:

```
<BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
```

Comment: I'm returning Visibility.Collapsed

Answer (score 0):

I did not test with binding but I have used successfully used binding in style before

```
<Menu>
    <Menu.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
        </Style>
    </Menu.Resources>
    <MenuItem Header="ONe" />
    <MenuItem Header="Two" />
    <MenuItem Header="Three" />
</Menu>
```